# WAMP MySQL error 2002

Tags: mysql, wamp

About a year ago I started working with databases. To this end I installed WAMP on my relatively old Windows 7 computer. That went very smooth, and since that time I am an enthousiastic user of WAMP, doing quite a lot of php programming.

Now I have a brand new Windows 8 tablet. After having installed Firefox and Thunderbird I tried to install WAMP, the latest version downloaded from Sourceforge (Apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.3, MySQL 5.5.24). Since Windows 8 is not really an obscure operating system, I did not expect any problems. However, I was heavily disappointed.

The first thing I had to do was inserting the line Allow from ::1 in the files alias/phpmyadmin.conf and httpd.conf. Then localhost worked, but phpmyadmin not. It gives the error MySQL #2002 - No connection could me made because the target  machine actively refused it. There is some information on this error on internet, but they do not deal with the password definition, which seems to be my problem.

The mysql.log shows (first lines omitted, they look OK)

```
130401 13:21:35  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.  
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at  
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html  
InnoDB: File name .\ib_logfile0  
InnoDB: File operation call: 'aio read'.  
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

This suggests that I have a MySQL login-error. That is suggested as well by the following behaviour: when I open the MySQL console, it asks for a password. There is no password (in the file my.ini the password line is commented out), so I press enter and the console closes immediately. Also, when I specify a password in my.ini and use that password, the console closes immediately.

Maybe this is a simple problem, but I have no idea how to tackle it. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does `ib_logfile0` get created?

Comment: Yes, I found that file. It is about 5MB. Notepad (I still have to install Notepad++) could not open it, it seems not to be a plain text file

Comment: make sure you specify a path for your data files ( described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html )